# Circle and Polygon Collision with Libgdx

Tags: java, collision-detection, polygon, libgdx, geometry

Is there a way in Libgdx to verify a collision between a Polygon and a Circle?

I saw the `Intersector` class but only found collision test for Circle and Rectangle. What about any other Polygon?

If I need to do it manually, what's the best way to do that using Libgdx?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I managed to create a collision test method between a Circle and a Polygon. At least, it works for me.

Here's the code:

```
public boolean overlaps(Polygon polygon, Circle circle) {
    float []vertices=polygon.getTransformedVertices();
    Vector2 center=new Vector2(circle.x, circle.y);
    float squareRadius=circle.radius*circle.radius;
    for (int i=0;i<vertices.length;i+=2){
        if (i==0){
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(vertices[vertices.length-2], vertices[vertices.length-1]), new Vector2(vertices[i], vertices[i+1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        } else {
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(vertices[i-2], vertices[i-1]), new Vector2(vertices[i], vertices[i+1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will this code work with PolyLine instead of Polygon ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know since I made this question/answer at 2 years ago =/

Comment: I checked this code. Yes this is working code for both variants. Polygon and PolyLine

Answer (score 14):

Sadly I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm adding this as another  answer instead...

Cristiano's excellent answer works for checking that the circle overlaps one of the line segments of the polygon, however it doesn't check for the more unusual case of the circle being fully contained inside the polygon, which could happen if a small fast moving circle collided with a large polygon.

I've repasted Cristiano's code below with a small change to fix the issue...

```
public static boolean overlaps(Polygon polygon, Circle circle) {
    float []vertices=polygon.getTransformedVertices();
    Vector2 center=new Vector2(circle.x, circle.y);
    float squareRadius=circle.radius*circle.radius;
    for (int i=0;i<vertices.length;i+=2){
        if (i==0){
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(vertices[vertices.length - 2], vertices[vertices.length - 1]), new Vector2(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        } else {
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(vertices[i-2], vertices[i-1]), new Vector2(vertices[i], vertices[i+1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return polygon.contains(circle.x, circle.y);
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, on the time I only needed to check collisions outside so, I didn't know that. Thanks for the update ;)

Comment: This needs to go into libgdx.

Comment: Just make sure not to create new vectors inside the method, otherwise the used memory will bloat fast. Use something like `tmpVector2.set(x, y)` in place of `new Vector2(x, y)` (where `tmpVector2` is a field).

Answer (score 0):

...and to follow up on Phil Anderson's excellent answer, here's my version which simply avoids creating new Vector2s every check and instead re-uses static instances of Vector2.

```
public class PolygonUtil {

static final Vector2 center = new Vector2();
static final Vector2 vec1 = new Vector2();
static final Vector2 vec2 = new Vector2();

public static boolean overlaps(Polygon polygon, Circle circle) {
    float []vertices=polygon.getTransformedVertices();
    center.set(circle.x, circle.y);
    float squareRadius=circle.radius*circle.radius;
    for (int i=0;i<vertices.length;i+=2){
        if (i==0){
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(vec1.set(vertices[vertices.length - 2], vertices[vertices.length - 1]),
                    vec2.set(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        } else {
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(vec1.set(vertices[i-2], vertices[i-1]), vec2.set(vertices[i], vertices[i+1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return polygon.contains(circle.x, circle.y);
}
```

}