# Triangle Collision with Rectangle/Circle in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to handle triangle intersections with rectangles and circles in LibGDX? I see the Intersector class has methods for testing intersections with triangles and rays, but I'm not sure how I can directly apply that to rectangles or circles. I also see there's an isPointInTriangle method, which I could perhaps use to cycle through the points of the triangle and rectangle?

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html

Maybe I'm just missing an easy, already existing function within LibGDX? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles and rectangles are both considered to be polygons so use libGDX Polygon class to describe your triangles and rectangles and then use Intersector class to intersect them.

For circles you can either:

1. Approximate it with polygon (say 10 points around in circle) and then use Intersector class.
2. Create your own custom circle to polygon collision checker.

A simple algorithm to check polygon and circle collision that comes to mind:

```
if center of circle is inside the polygon =>>> they overlap.

else if distance between circle center and any of the polygons vertices is less then circle radius =>>> they overlap.

else =>>> they dont overlap.
```

This is considering you don't need to know what exactly is the overlapping portion of these figures and you only want to know if they overlap. If you need to know the overlapping portion then approximating your circle with polygon is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually able to find this as well, and just create my own intersector class as you mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323719/circle-and-polygon-collision-with-libgdx

Comment: Just so you know, the method you linked is less efficient than the one i stated and it also should produce a lot of garbage if called repeatedly due to new Vector2 being created every time you call it. But if there are't too many circles in your game you might be fine with that.

Comment: Thanks- I'm going to try and rework it, but it's suitable for now. I only have one circle, and at most 10 polygons, so I don't expect performance issues for now.

Comment: You don't need to approximate your circle with polygons to know the overlapping portion!