# Collision Polygon and Circle - Lingdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to detect when a polygon and a Circle collide. Other possibility that i have think is with rectangle, but it can't be possible because i want to rotate the rectangle, so what is the solution?

Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323719/circle-and-polygon-collision-with-libgdx?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **Intersector** class in LibGDX, it should work just fine for your needs. 
*libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html*

Use **intersectSegmentCircle** method. 
It does take Vector2 variables as arguments, so you have to use Vector2 for storing x and y coordinates of your points - circle center and polygon vertices. 
There are also Polygon and Circle classes, you can use those for storing coordinates as Vector2.

Anyway, lets assume you already have circle and polygon described by set of Vector2 points:

```
Vector2 circleCenter, PolyVertex1, PolyVertex2, PolyVertex3, ..., PolyVertexN;
```

There are line segments between polygon vertices, you have to check, if any of those segments intersects with circle. So, for every pair of verices, check, if:

```
intersectSegmentCircle(PolyVertex1, PolyVertex2, circleCenter, radius^2);
intersectSegmentCircle(PolyVertex2, PolyVertex3, circleCenter, radius^2);
...
intersectSegmentCircle(PolyVertexN-1, PolyVertexN, circleCenter, radius^2);
intersectSegmentCircle(PolyVertexN, PolyVertex1), circleCenter, radius^2);
```

returns true. If yes, it means your polygon and circle colided.

In some cases (small circle and large polygon), there can be no intersection between polygon edges and circle, whole circle can be inside polygon. Then you will have to use **isPointInPolygon()** method. It takes Array of Vector2 (polygon vertices) and Vector2 (cirlce center) as arguments. 
So, store polygon vertices in array, and check if isPointInPolygon returns true. If yes, then again, there is collision.

```
Array <Vector2> PolyVertices;
...
isPointInPolygon(PolyVertices,circleCenter);
```

Dont copy&paste above code, wont work because of lack of initialization and thelike ;) But i hope, idea is clear.

Comment: Yes, but I have a problem, when i do it with polygon is very imprecise, the circle no stop on the segment, but when I do it with Rectangle it is precise. What it is the problem?

Comment: @PABLO No idea. Maybye if you show code, someone will be able to point out?