# Make Custom Shape JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a 2D game in JavaFX and when detecting collisions, I am getting rather inaccurate results due to the player sprite being set as the fill of a rectangle and therefore not having the intended borders. Is there a way I could make my own shape so thatI could get as accurate as possible?

Another idea I had is checking if the pixel that collided was transparent and then not ending the game if it was. Does anyone know of a way I can get the coordinates of the pixel that collides so that from there I can use PixelReader to check?

If anyone knows a better way, please let me know!

Thanks, 
Ethan

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this.  Here is one way I have used with good success.  I would make hit boxes, that were themselves rectangles.  Then during collision detection, I would iterate through all the hit boxes to see if they collided with the flying projectile's hit boxes.

What this allows you to do is fill in complex shapes with smaller rectangles.  For example a plane would have one long horizontal rectangle and one smaller rectangle crossing at the middle.

Currently I am using libGDX.  In libGDX I use their Polygon object as stated here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28540488/1490322  I have not seen similar functionality in JavaFX, but it would not be hard to copy what libGDX is doing into JavaFX code... their code is open sourced.